# $L^p$ estimates for scalar conservation laws

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the initial value problem for scalar conservation laws

$$\begin{eqnarray} u_t+f(u)_x=0\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x) \end{eqnarray}$$

1. If $u_0 \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ we have $\Vert u(.,t)\Vert_{\infty} \leq \Vert u_0\Vert_{\infty}$
2. If $u_0 \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ we have $\Vert u(.,t)\Vert_{1} \leq \Vert u_0\Vert_{1}$ (which follows from the contraction principle)

Do we have such results for other values of $p \in (0,\infty)$ ? If so how to prove it?

Any comments or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Saad any $p \in (0, \infty)$

Comment: For convex fluxes, there are some time decay estimates you might find interesting. Maybe the works by Tai-Ping Liu, in the mid 80s, could be a good starting point.

Comment: @AugSB Thanks for the comments...May I know the title of the paper?

Comment: *Source-solutions and asymptotic behavior in conservation laws*, by Tai-Ping Liu and Michel Pierre (1984), could be one. I think there are more on that, but I cannot find them now, so I let that to you, sorry.

Comment: If $u_0\in L^1\cap L^\infty$ then the answer is yes by Lebesgue interpolation

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks for the comment..But, I din get you completely... answer is yes for which $p?$. Are there any additional assumptions on flux? please mention the refference.

Comment: I have no reference, just Holder's inequality. I assume that you can prove your two inequalities, and the above condition on $u_0$. Full proof - $$ \|fg\|_{L^p} \le \|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^\infty} = \||f|^p\|_{L^1}^{1/p}\||g|^q\|_{L^\infty}^{1/q}$$
then set $f = |u|^{1/p}$ and $g = |u|^{1/q}$. This gives
$$ \|u\|_{L^p} \le \|u\|_{L^1}^{1/p} \|u\|_{L^\infty}^{1/q} \le \|u_0\|_{L^1}^{1/p} \|u_0\|_{L^\infty}^{1/q}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u\in C([0,T];L^{1}(\mathbb{R}))$ be an entropy solution. Then for each convex entropy function $\eta,$ the entropy condition implies the following.
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\eta(u(x,t))dx \leq \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\eta(u(x,0))dx.$$
Choosing $\eta(u)=u^p$ we get the desired $L^p$ bounds on the entropy solution.

P.S.: However, for weak solutions in general such $L^p$ bounds do not exist for any $p \in (0,\infty].$